# i got error"System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.RadioButtons.<init>: line 8, column 1"

Tags: visualforce

Controller code:

```
public class RadioButtons {
    public List<Questions__c> qc {get;set;} 
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
    public String selectedValue { get; set; }   
    public RadioButtons ()
    { 

        for (Integer i = 0; i < qc.size(); i++) {
        rows = new List<Row>();
        rows.add(new Row('va', 'Yes'));
        rows.add(new Row('vb', 'No'));
        rows.add(new Row('vc', 'Unlikely'));
        rows.add(new Row('vc', 'Maybe'));
        }
    }

    public PageReference Submit() {
        System.debug('SFDC: ' + selectedValue);
        return null;
    } 

    public class Row {
        public String Value { get; set; }
        public String Label { get; set; }
        public Boolean isChecked { get; set; }

        public Row(String Value, String Label) {
            this.Value = Value;
            this.Label = Label;
        } 
    }
}
```

vf code:

```
<apex:page controller="RadioButtons">
    <apex:form ><p/>
    <apex:pageblock id="Questions">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!qc}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Question_asked__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Submit}" rerender="out" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!rows}" var="r" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="{!r.Value}" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.RadioButtonValue}');" /> {!r.Label}
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>    
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!selectedValue}" id="RadioButtonValue" />
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputText value="{!selectedValue}" id="out"/>
    <script>
        function changeValue(input, textid) {
            document.getElementById(textid).value = input.value;
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You will also need to move `rows = new List<Row>();` to be before the loop.

Comment: Nikita.. If this issue solved then mark the best Ans and close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `qc.size()` without ever initializing `qc`. Your `List<Questions>` ostensibly needs to be queried for or loaded in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor first initialize `List<Questions__c>` then access `qc.size()`

**Note:** If list is empty then your for loop will not iterate.. looks like you need query `Questions__c` object

```
public RadioButtons ()
    { 
         qc = new   List<Questions__c>(); //Add this line
        for (Integer i = 0; i < qc.size(); i++) {
        rows = new List<Row>();
        rows.add(new Row('va', 'Yes'));
        rows.add(new Row('vb', 'No'));
        rows.add(new Row('vc', 'Unlikely'));
        rows.add(new Row('vc', 'Maybe'));
        }
    }
```